# Combining URI and Refer cobinations from Apache with pig

Tags: logging, apache-pig

I will start by stating that I am a sysadmin by trade and PIG newbie, so please be gentle.

I am attempting to use PIG to parse Apache web logs from our CDN.    For one application, we have three distinct call types which can be gathered from the URI and 3 different App/Version strings (caused by inconsistency in app development).   I need to gather them and produce one report detailing the number of each type of call by each app/version.

The call types will contain on of the following:   **valid, wms, tile**
The App name in the userAgent field can look like the following:

**APP%20NAME/0.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/13.0.0"**

**Android APP NAME 0.0.0 (SCH-I605 - Android 4.1.2, SDK XX)**

**APP NAME 0.0.0 (iPhone OS 6.1.3 - iPhone, XXX.XX.XXX.XX.XXXX, XXXXXXXX 0.0)"**

This is what I had working before I discovered the inconsistency of userAgent naming.   Probably a hack at best, but it was producing what was needed.

Any help is appreciated.

```
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
DEFINE LogLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.apachelog.CombinedLogLoader();
DEFINE DayExtractor org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.util.apachelogparser.DateExtractor('yyyy-MM-dd');
DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT;
logs = LOAD '$INPUT' USING LogLoader as (remoteAddr, remoteLogname, user, time, method, uri, proto, status, bytes, referer,userAgent);
FILTERED = FILTER logs by userAgent matches '.*MapKit.*' OR userAgent matches '.*Darwin.*' or userAgent matches '.*Android.*';
DARWINONLY = FOREACH FILTERED GENERATE DayExtractor(time) as day, uri, bytes, userAgent;
FILTERVALID = FILTER DARWINONLY BY uri matches '.*valid.*';
FILTERTILE = FILTER DARWINONLY BY uri matches '.*tile.*';
FILTERWMS = FILTER DARWINONLY BY uri matches '.*wms.*';
VALIDAPPTIME = FOREACH FILTERVALID GENERATE day as validframeday, EXTRACT(userAgent, '([^\\s]+)') as validframeapp,bytes as validbytes;
WMSAPPTIME = FOREACH FILTERWMS GENERATE day as wmsday, EXTRACT(userAgent, '([^\\s]+)') as wmsapp,  bytes as wmsbytes;
TILEAPPTIME = FOREACH FILTERTILE GENERATE day as tileday, EXTRACT(userAgent, '([^\\s]+)') as tileapp, bytes as tilebytes;
GROUPWMS = GROUP WMSAPPTIME BY ($0,$1);
GROUPTILE = GROUP TILEAPPTIME BY ($0,$1);
GROUPVALID = GROUP VALIDAPPTIME BY ($0,$1);
WMSAPPCOUNT = FOREACH GROUPWMS GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT($1) as wmsnum, SUM(WMSAPPTIME.wmsbytes) as wmstotalbytes;
VALIDAPPCOUNT = FOREACH GROUPVALID GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT($1) as validnum, SUM(VALIDAPPTIME.validbytes) as validtotalbytes;
TILEAPPCOUNT = FOREACH GROUPTILE GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT($1) as tilenum, SUM(TILEAPPTIME.tilebytes) as tiletotalbytes:int;
Y = COGROUP VALIDAPPCOUNT BY (validframeday,validframeapp), WMSAPPCOUNT BY (wmsday,wmsapp), TILEAPPCOUNT BY (tileday,tileapp);
Z = FOREACH Y GENERATE group as dailyapp, VALIDAPPCOUNT.validnum, VALIDAPPCOUNT.validtotalbytes, WMSAPPCOUNT.wmsnum, WMSAPPCOUNT.wmstotalbytes, TILEAPPCOUNT.tilenum, TILEAPPCOUNT.tiletotalbytes;
STORE Z into '$OUTPUT';
```

Comment: Could you add to/rewrite your question to indicate what your specific problem is? Is it with the regex for separating the data based on call types? Also, you should remove any code that doesn't directly pertain to your issue, it is a little overwhelming having to read all of it.